# Migrating to java 11 & jacoco 0.8.4

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco, java-11, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have migrated to Java 11 from Java 8. Below are the plugin changes made:

```
Java version : 11
Jacoco version : 0.8.4
```

But on updating these, code coverage is not showing up. Earlier it was showing while on java 8.

Comment: Do you see any error in the logs?

Comment: No error in logs. The build is success. Only the code coverage has dropped to NA

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838995/jacoco-code-coverage-dropped-with-migration-to-java-11?rq=1

Comment: the issue was due to sonar was on lower version. migrating it to higher version 6 fixed the issue.

Comment: glad you found the solution. You can add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upgrading sonar version to 6 fixed the issue